# Why does scala not see my hello.class as a program in command prompt?

Tags: scala

I am trying to run scala program in cmd prompt. And I get the message.

"No, such file or class on class path exists."

Things that may be relevant:

1. I had several warnings from Windows about downloading and running the scala executable from the site. (I ignored them all )
2. I had to enter a Admin Command Line to use scala, and it did not show up in my program files after install.
3. The installer never actually popped up for me. So I ran the executable as administration, now
   it appears in my program X86 folder. and I can enter scala mode without being in Admin mode.   4. The .scala file does compile. with scalac hello.scala
4. The code given to me by my instructor, in a file I named hello.scala `object hello extends App{ println("Hello") }`

[image: Snip of my file folder after scalac command]

Finally, I have looked at 2 Youtube videos and 2 Stack posts before asking this question. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Also, why not just using **IntelliJ**?

Comment: Because the professor requires us to do it both ways. She relaxed that a little when I zoomed her and showed her the problem. She could not help either.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete transcript of a successful session compiling and running on this code:

```
% echo 'object hello extends App{ println("Hello") }' > hello.scala
% scalac hello.scala             
% scala hello       
Hello
```

Are you doing something different? If so, what is it? Show a transcript of your entire effort, including all commands you entered and all error messages you got.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The code in my post is the code I used, however it is on a .scala file in a directory. I navigate to the directory in the windows command line `cd <path/tomy/dir>`
Next I compile `scalac hello.scala`
That works as I can see in file explorer the population of the files as shown in post. 

Then I run the command

    scala hello
Nothing happens, it says that it cannot find the file. I have a screenshot of the exact message I will add when I get back to my computer. I had to remove it as it showed my file path and name. I will crop it and re add it.